# Cache efficient way to implement a list of a priori bounded size

Tags: c++

I have a list for which I have an a priori set bound as a configuration option that it will never grow above `N` elements. Thus, it will fill up to `N` elements and after that the only operation I need to support is moving an element in the list to the end of the list.

Ideally, I would like to have a data structure, where I have list nodes that contain a pointer to the stored object. Since I know there will be `N` list nodes at the most, I could allocate them contiguously in memory, so that jumping around the list would presumably be a fast operation, since elements in the list would probably be warm in the cache.

Is it possible to have the STL `std::list` allocate its nodes in this way, i.e. can this be done with a custom allocator (I've never tried to write a custom allocator for an STL class before).

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::vector`, or even `std::array` in this case?

Comment: I guess it's possible, in a way it's turning the list in to vector. Some might as well stick to vector.

Comment: What's wrong with using a vector? Because on every access of the list I need to move the element accessed to the front while preserving the relative order of the other elements. This is not efficient on a vector, i.e. I want the O(1) complexity of the list operation combined with the elements accessed being mostly warm in the cache.